# Git-Bundle creating a empty .bundle?

Tags: git, git-bundle

I have cloned a repository and created a local branch named main.

After that I made some changes in the code, committed and wanted to create a .bundle with the commits.

I generate the .bundle using `git bundle create test.bundle main` and want to unbundle the commits to check if the file is made correct but when I `git clone test.bundle` its just generate a folder with nothing inside.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Git bundle is not a repository. It only contains objects (blobs, trees and commits) but no *references* (branches, tags, etc.)

When you clone a bundle into a new directory, you get all the commits in that bundle, but no branches or tags to refer to those commits. You need to find the commits and create references for them so they're "reachable".

Here's an example that I reproduced locally:

```bash
$ git -C ~/ibugone.com bundle create ~/test.bundle master
Enumerating objects: 6456, done.
Counting objects: 100% (6456/6456), done.
Compressing objects: 100% (3140/3140), done.
Total 6456 (delta 4279), reused 4682 (delta 3063), pack-reused 0

$ git clone ~/test.bundle t
Cloning into 't'...
Receiving objects: 100% (6456/6456), 1.30 MiB | 46.08 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (4279/4279), done.
warning: remote HEAD refers to nonexistent ref, unable to checkout.

$ ls -A t
.git

$ git -C ~/ibugone.com log --format=oneline -1
9178ac099b2ea8dc6221acfab8fde074355ef07c (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD) Fix junk items

$ git -C t log --format=oneline -1
fatal: your current branch 'master' does not have any commits yet

128| $ git -C t log --format=oneline -1 9178ac0
9178ac099b2ea8dc6221acfab8fde074355ef07c (origin/master) Fix junk items

$ git -C t reset --hard 9178ac0
HEAD is now at 9178ac0 Fix junk items

$ git -C t log --format=oneline -1
9178ac099b2ea8dc6221acfab8fde074355ef07c (HEAD -> master, origin/master) Fix junk items

$
```

I create a bundle `~/test.bundle` from my development repo. Then I clone it to `~/t/t`. The new repo contains no branches (because the bundle does not), but I can create a branch from a commit in the new repo (`git reset` operates on the default branch on an empty repo). Then there's the `master` branch in the new repo.

Comment: What if the person that is trying to unbundle the file does not have the "9178ac0" hash that refers to the commit? How is them supposed to unbundle?

Comment: @Lemon_prog You tell them to use `git bundle list-heads` to inspect the file.

Comment: Technically, a bundle also contains stuff that can become references: `bundle` implements the server's side of a `git fetch` operation. As you mentioned, see `git bundle list-heads`. (But a bundle need not have the full set of heads, or any heads at all.) Fetching *from* a bundle does the same thing as `git fetch` from a server, so you wind up with remote-tracking names instead of branch names.

Comment: The remote-tracking thing is why you have an `origin/master` above. Your current branch after cloning *from* the bundle is a branch that doesn't exist, though, and that's where all the problems come in. (Note that you're normally expected to add a bundle as a remote, rather than cloning it, but either way ends up doing the same thing in this particular case, since the clone operation adds the bundle as remote `origin`.)